# How do I alphabetize an array of objects where the strings are fields in the objects

Tags: c++, arrays, alphabetical

I have a name class defined like this in C++:

```
class name{
public:
  int range;
  int num;
  char type;
  string n;
};
```

How do I alphabetize an array that contains names based on the `string n`?

Comment: Forget that it's a property of a class for a minute.  Could you sort the strings alphabetically on their own?  Start there.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to overload `operator<` to compare its `n` with another object's (of the same type) `n`. If a `name` is identified by its `n` variable and `n` defines its ordering this may be an appropriate solution.

For sorting, there are functions in the algorithms library to do this.

The overload will look something like this:

```
bool operator<(const name &o) const {
  return n < o.n;
}
```

It would also be a good idea to define the other five comparison operators. Equality is easy enough, then the rest can be defined in terms of `<` and `==`

```
bool operator==(const name &o) const {
  return n == o.n;
}
```

Comment: No you don't... I mean, this is a method for doing it, but now you're defining what `<` and `==` are for the entire class just to sort them alphabetically based on one property of the class...

Comment: Based on the name of the class, it seems appropriate to define equality and ordering based on the variable `n`.

Comment: It `might` be appropriate, but we don't necessarily know that.  Your answer states "You need to overload".  An array of objects of this class can be sorted on the `n` property without overloading `n` and without modifying or defining any new behaviors for the class.

Comment: I edited the answer to include weasel words to make it clear the solution is not "need to overload."

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` optionally takes a predicate, which can be a function, lambda or something else that's callable. Here you can just write a simple function `bool orderByName(name const& A, name const& B)`.